# How to do periodic Google Place API Calls?

Tags: android, service, gps, google-places

I need to send what businesses the user is currently at every 5 minutes. I am using the Google Places library and can successfully grab the businesses. The problem is this service needs to be going 24/7.

My solution so far is to use a service called from my main activity. This service will subscribe to background location updates every 5 minutes. Once the location update comes through, it will ask the Google Place library for the businesses the user is currently at. I am using the Google Play Services to subscribe to these location updates. I read that using an Alarm for something like this isn't recommended, that is why I am subscribing to location updates to give me a pseudo setTimeout(5mins) behavior. I am actually not even using the GPS returned, just the function callback to ask GooglePlaces.

The problem is that this service is unbelievably unreliable. I am running Android 8.0 with 11.2.0 play services installed. The service's OnDestroy is called within a few minutes and is never restarted even though I return Start_sticky from the service OnStartCommand. Are services supposed to get killed this quickly? I have no other apps open and the service is 99% of the time just idle waiting for the location tick to come through.

Is there a better way to do this? All I really need is a function called every 5 minutes so I can ask Google Place where the user is at. It doesn't even have to be location related. The only requirements are it runs even when the app is closed.

Comment: If your app goes into the background, your service will be killed off immediately in Android 8. You need to run a foreground service to accomplish what you are wanting to do. However, why are you trying to get place information when the user is not using the app?

Comment: I cant go into too much detail, but the purpose is to recommend businesses to people based on where they go.

Comment: Why not store the points, and use a `JobScheduler` to batch the calls for Google Places? This way, you don't use too much power making a network call and taking GPS every 5 minutes.

Comment: Well technically I don't even need the GPS points. The Place call that I'm making doesn't take any GPS parameters. It uses this call here: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/current-place

Comment: I just need a reliable way to make that call every few minutes. The user below suggested AlarmManager but idk how effective that would be.

Comment: Make the service into a foreground service. It'll lift the location restrictions in Android 8, it'll keep your service running, and allows you to make network calls even when your app is in the background.

Comment: Okay I will use a foreground service. Once the foreground service is started, how do I call a function every 5 minutes or so? Would using a Handler or Runnable be the ideal way?

Comment: You can use a handler if it has to be very precise, but honestly, use an AlarmManager with a non-exact alarm if it doesn't have to be, as it will allow the system to wake up in a power efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **AlarmManager** with service... try this once maybe it will solve your problem.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use AlarmManager started from my Activity. No Services needed.